# load data into a UIWebView created programmatically

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm setting up a ViewController that will hold a couple of UIViews, including UIWebView

I'm creating and adding those Views programmatically in the viewDidLoad method.

Is this approach satisfactory? or am I doing something too expensive for the hardware.

and how do I load new data into a WebView that was created in the ViewDidLoad method.

I have a properly of type UIWebView, then in the ViewDidLoad i do:

```
detailsView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 0, 512, 768)];
```

and this does not seem to work:

```
- (void)loadDetailedContent:(NSString *)s
{
    [detailsView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
    [detailsView reload];
}
```

Waiting for your reply, thank you in advance

Comment: but what's happening? did you addSubview of UIWebView ? Do you have internet connection ?

Comment: the detailsView is nil when i call it from loadDetailedContent

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly create and add subviews in your viewController's `viewDidLoad` programmatically, but you'll have to remember to call `addSubview` if you want them to appear on the screen.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    detailsView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(500, 0, 512, 768)];
    [self.view addSubview:detailsView];
}
```

As for your second question about loading data into your webview, there is no need to call `reload` immediately after calling `loadRequest:`.

```
- (void)loadDetailedContent:(NSString *)s
{
    [detailsView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
}
```

Comment: I did add them to the main view controller but now i want to load data, but it has no effect, thanks for reply

Comment: The problem is detailsView is nil at that time, does that mean i must reinitialize it with a frame and add it to a subview each time i want to load new data?

Comment: detailsView should not be nil since you initialize it during viewDidLoad.  Do you mean that you are calling loadDetailedContent before viewDidLoad runs?

Comment: no I'm calling it after the viewDidLoad but still it's null I have no clue

Comment: @property (nonatomic, retain) UIWebView *detailsView;

this is how the property looks, maybe the problem is in here?

Comment: Your property declaration is correct.  So to clarify: you are saying that 1) `detailsView` is nil when loadDetailedContent runs, 2) you are initializing `detailsView` in viewDidLoad, and 3) viewDidLoad is running before loadDetailedContent.  Unless something else is going on in your code that you haven't described in your question, one of those three assumptions must be incorrect.  Where in your code are you calling loadDetailedContent?

Comment: i run the loadDetailedContent after a view is touched, that apparently happens when everything is loaded it looks like the detailsView is released at some point, could it be happening automatically without my knowledge?

Comment: any idea what could be happening? I'm lost

Comment: You are using `retain` when declaring your property, so once set it shouldn't be released unless you explicitly do so.  Just a hunch - are you calling loadDetailedContent in a `prepareForSegue` method?